# Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Data Export entities not showing?

Tags: export, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I have an instance of Dynamics 365 FnO Version 10.0.6 Platform update 30. I am trying to export Asset Management data from my environment. I have verified that there is data in the Assets and Assets Type table.

I am following the below steps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-import-export-job

I am stuck in the UI because I am unable to select any entities from "+ Add Entity". The field is simply greyed out. Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Have tried chrome/edge/firefox

[image: before select entity]
[image: cant select grey box]

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your entities? See https://dynamics365ax2012.blogspot.com/2018/07/how-to-refresh-data-entity-list-in.html .

Comment: thanks, this was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply refresh the entities by going to  Data Management -> framework parameters -> entity settings -> refresh entity list.

Allow the job to complete and the full list should now render.